# What's the probability density function of this sampling strategy?

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling

Let's say I want to design a sampling procedure, which samples a real number from the sample space [0, X]. The sampling is done in 3 steps:

Step 1: Sample [0, X] M times using a given PDF, say PDF1.

Step 2: Sample [0, X] N times using another given PDF, say PDF2.

Step 3: Random sample the M+N samples to generate the final sample.

What's the overall PDF of my sampling strategy? It must be a function of PDF1, PDF2, M, and N, but I couldn't figure it out. Any thoughts or pointers?

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be the probability density function of the first PDF, and $g(x)$ be the density of thes second PDF. Then you simply want $Mf(x)/(M+N) + Ng(x)/(M+N)$

Comment: Intuitively sounds right! How do we go about proving it?

Comment: Are you familiar with conditioning?

Comment: I guess I understand conditional probability, but don't see the connection. Would you please shed some light upon this?